# Got error trigger Jenkins builds by pushing to Github

Tags: github, jenkins

I config Jenkins deploy PHP app by trigger the script deployment whenever developers pushed their code to Github with domain .mydomain.com. If developer create new branch and push some changes to that branch, it works perfectly fine, the strange thing is when developer create new branch and push to server (don't change anything just 
create new branch and push) it doesn't trigger the script deployment.
Could you please help?
[image]

Comment: Hi, your problem statement is not clear to me, can you elaborate the issue you are facing? And could you also post the error displayed in Jenkins?

Comment: @RejeeshChandran I config Jenkins with the script deployment my PHP app whenever developers push their code to GitHub with domain *<branch_name>.mydomain.com. If developer create new branch and push some changes to that branch, it works perfectly fine, the strange thing is when developer create new branch and push to server (don't change anything just create new branch and push) it doesn't trigger the script deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git configuration there is a field `Branch Specifier (blank for default):` if you put there `**` it will build all branches from all remotes.

But if you are creating a new branch and push to server it won't trigger the job. As Github plugin in Jenkins configuration is monitoring the changes in the repo and creating a branch is not a change. So the job won't trigger for that branch until you do a commit in that branch. And I feel this is the correct behavior.

> For example when you do a commit `xxxx` on branch `master`, your job
>   gets triggered with commit id `xxxx`. Now you create a branch say
>   `branch1` from master and you push to server. As you can see there is
>   not difference between commit `xxxx` and `branch1` so there is no need
>   to build `branch1` in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, I feel this is the correct behavior too. But is there any document say that?

Comment: You need to go through the documentation of each Jenkins Plugin which is you can easily find via Google search.

Comment: Do you know any Jenkins plugins that can trigger the job whenever new branch push to server without changes though